# Install python htseq package in specific path with apt-get

Tags: python, path, package, apt-get

I want to install the python-htseq package so that I might use it when I run python from command line. However, my used python is in:

```
$ which python
/home/name/bin/Anaconda3/bin/python
```

while the package gets installed in:

```
$ dpkg -L python-htseq
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/HTSeq/_HTSeq.so
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/HTSeq/_HTSeq_internal.py
```

is there a way for me to indicate for which python the package should be installed?

I've also tried to install the package with pip but I get an error message:

```
Command "/home/name/bin/Anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-vr1w43uw/HTSeq/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-wbat5dk9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-vr1w43uw/HTSeq/
```

Is there a way I can avoid any of the above issues?

Thanky in advance for any help!